# SQLCMD cannot connect my named instance

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using SQL Server 2017 based on Windows server 2016. I am trying to connect my named instance, but I got the error message as below screenshot:
[image: Can not connect to SQL instance by SQLCMD]

So I tried to reinstall ODBC Driver 13. But I got the error as follow:
[image: reinstall ODBC Driver 13]

Even after I uninstalled ODBC Driver 17, I still got the same error message.
Any thought?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Is the SQL Server Browser running on your server?

Comment: Does SSMS connect from the same machine? Are you on the same subnet? Maybe try with the IP address.

Comment: I disabled browser...and also tried IP address instead...I can connect by using -S (capital letter) instead of -s (lowercase) now. Thanks to Randolph and you guys help. Have a great one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the server name with `-S` (capital letter) instead of `-s` (lowercase).

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility):

```
   -s col_separator  
   -S [protocol:]server[instance_name][,port]
```